# BLE CallBack onCharacteristicChanged is not call back

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am a student working with BLE, and I am not good at English, so please understand it with the help of Google Translator.
Since the BLE notification does not work during the work, it is difficult to attach the source, so please help.

`boolean success4 = mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);` is false but I don't know why.

```java
        // Debugging
        private static final String TAG = "BleManager";

        // Constants that indicate the current connection state
        public static final int STATE_ERROR = -1;
        public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;        // Initialized
        public static final int STATE_IDLE = 1;        // Not connected
        public static final int STATE_SCANNING = 2;    // Scanning
        public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 13;    // Connecting
        public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 16;    // Connected

        // Message types sent from the BluetoothManager to Handler
        public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
        public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
        public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
        public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

        public static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;    // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        public static final long SCAN_INTERVAL = 5 * 60 * 1000;

        // System, Management
        private static Context mContext = null;
        Handler mHandler;
        private boolean connect = false;

        // Bluetooth
        private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
        private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
        private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mcharacteristic;

        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        private BluetoothDevice mDefaultDevice = null;

        private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt = null;

        private ArrayList<BluetoothGattService> mGattServices
                = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattService>();
        private BluetoothGattService mDefaultService = null;
        private ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> mGattCharacteristics
                = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
        private ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> mWritableCharacteristics
                = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
        private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mDefaultChar = null;


        // Parameters
        private int mState = -1;

        private void BleManager() {

            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
            //mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            mState = STATE_NONE;
            mContext = this;
            if (mContext == null) {return;}
            else
            {
                scanLeDevice(true);
            }

        }

        public synchronized void finalize() {
            // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
            if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                mState = STATE_IDLE;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                disconnect();
            }

            mDefaultDevice = null;
            mBluetoothGatt = null;
            mDefaultService = null;
            mGattServices.clear();
            mGattCharacteristics.clear();
            mWritableCharacteristics.clear();

            if (mContext == null)
                return;

            // Don't forget this!!
            // Unregister broadcast listeners
            // mContext.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }

        /*****************************************************
         *  Private methods
         ******************************************************/

        /**
         * This method extracts UUIDs from advertised data
         * Because Android native code has bugs in parsing 128bit UUID
         * use this method instead.
         */

        private void stopScanning() {
            if (mState < STATE_CONNECTING) {
                mState = STATE_IDLE;
            }
            scanLeDevice(false);
            //mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }

        /**
         * Check services and looking for writable characteristics
         */
        private int checkGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
                Log.e("# BluetoothAdapter", " not initialized");
                return -1;
            }

            for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
                // Default service info

                Log.e("# GATT Service:", " " + gattService.getUuid().toString());

                // Remember service
                mGattServices.add(gattService);

                // Extract characteristics
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattService.getCharacteristics();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {

                    // Remember characteristic
                    mGattCharacteristics.add(gattCharacteristic);
                    for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor:gattCharacteristic.getDescriptors()){
                        Log.e("# GATT Char:", gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString());
                        Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothGattDescriptor: " + descriptor.getUuid().toString());
                    }

                    boolean isWritable = isWritableCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                    if (isWritable) {
                        mWritableCharacteristics.add(gattCharacteristic);
                    }

                    boolean isReadable = isReadableCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                    if (isReadable) {
                        readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                    }

                    if (isNotificationCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic) && gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString().equals("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")) {

                        setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);

                        if (gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString().equals("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")) {
                            Log.e("default", "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
                            mDefaultChar = gattCharacteristic;
                            Log.e("default", "////////////////////////////////////////////// " + mDefaultChar.getUuid().toString());
                            //break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return mWritableCharacteristics.size();
        }

        private boolean isWritableCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic chr) {
            if (chr == null) return false;

            final int charaProp = chr.getProperties();
            if (((charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) |
                    (charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE)) > 0) {
                Log.e("# Found writable", " characteristic");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.e("# Not writable", " characteristic");
                return false;
            }
        }

        private boolean isReadableCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic chr) {
            if (chr == null) return false;

            final int charaProp = chr.getProperties();
            if ((charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                Log.e("# Found readable", " characteristic");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.e("# Not readable", " characteristic");
                return false;
            }
        }

        private boolean isNotificationCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic chr) {
            if (chr == null) return false;

            final int charaProp = chr.getProperties();
            if ((charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                Log.e("# Found notification", " characteristic");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.e("# Not notification", " characteristic");
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read result is reported
         * asynchronously through the {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
         * callback.
         *
         * @param characteristic The characteristic to read from.
         */
        public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
                Log.e("# BluetoothAdapter", " not initialized");
                return;
            }
            mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

        /**
         * Enables or disables notification on a give characteristic.
         *
         * @param characteristic Characteristic to act on.
         * @param enabled        If true, enable notification.  False otherwise.
         */
        public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                                  boolean enabled) {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
                Log.e("# BluetoothAdapter ", "not initialized");
                return;
            }
            characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);

            boolean success1 = mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
            //00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
            //public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
            Log.e("info1",characteristic.getUuid().toString() + " // " + characteristic.getValue() + " // " + enabled + " // " + success1);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
            Log.e("info2",characteristic.getUuid().toString() + " // " + characteristic.getValue() + " // " + enabled);
            boolean success3 = descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            boolean success2 = descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
            Log.e("info3",characteristic.getUuid().toString() + " // " + characteristic.getValue() + " // " + enabled + " // " + success3 + " // " + success2);
            //boolean success5 = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
            boolean success4 = mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
            Log.e("info4",descriptor.getCharacteristic() + " // " + descriptor.getValue() + " // " + descriptor.getPermissions() + " // " + descriptor.getUuid() + " // " + enabled + " // " + success4);

            //mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
        }


        /*****************************************************
         *  Public methods
         ******************************************************/

        public int getState() {
            return mState;
        }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

        private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(device.getName() != null && device.getName().equals("AINTEL_MFD") && connect == false){
                                connect = true;
                                scanLeDevice(false);
                                Log.e("ScanDevice",device.getName() + " // " + device.getUuids() + " // " + device.getAddress() + " // " + rssi + " // " + scanRecord[0] + " // " + scanRecord[1]);
                                connectGatt(Vars.mContext,false, device);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

        public boolean scanLeDevice(final boolean enable, UUID[] uuid) {
            boolean isScanStarted = false;
            if (enable) {
                if (mState == STATE_SCANNING)
                    return false;

                if (mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(uuid, mLeScanCallback)) {
                    mState = STATE_SCANNING;
                    mDeviceList.clear();

                    // If you want to scan for only specific types of peripherals
                    // call below function instead
                    //startLeScan(UUID[], BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback);

                    // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            stopScanning();
                        }
                    }, SCAN_PERIOD);

                    isScanStarted = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (mState < STATE_CONNECTING) {
                    mState = STATE_IDLE;
                }
                stopScanning();
            }

            return isScanStarted;
        }

        public boolean connectGatt(Context c, boolean bAutoReconnect, BluetoothDevice device) {
            if (c == null || device == null)
                return false;

            mGattServices.clear();
            mGattCharacteristics.clear();
            mWritableCharacteristics.clear();

            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(c, bAutoReconnect, mGattCallback);
            mDefaultDevice = device;

            mState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        }

        public boolean connectGatt(Context c, boolean bAutoReconnect, String address) {
            if (c == null || address == null)
                return false;

            if (mBluetoothGatt != null && mDefaultDevice != null
                    && address.equals(mDefaultDevice.getAddress())) {
                if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                    mState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            BluetoothDevice device =
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(address);
            if (device == null) {
                Log.e("# Device not found. ", "Unable to connect.");
                return false;
            }

            mGattServices.clear();
            mGattCharacteristics.clear();
            mWritableCharacteristics.clear();

            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(c, bAutoReconnect, mGattCallback);
            mDefaultDevice = device;

            mState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
         * is reported asynchronously through the
         * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
         * callback.
         */
        public void disconnect() {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
                Log.e("# BluetoothAdapter", " not initialized");
                return;
            }
            mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
        }

        public boolean write(BluetoothGattCharacteristic chr, byte[] data) {
            if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "# BluetoothGatt not initialized");
                return false;
            }

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic writableChar = null;

            if (chr == null) {
                if (mDefaultChar == null) {
                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic bgc : mWritableCharacteristics) {
                        if (isWritableCharacteristic(bgc)) {
                            writableChar = bgc;
                        }
                    }
                    if (writableChar == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "# Write failed - No available characteristic");
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (isWritableCharacteristic(mDefaultChar)) {
                        Log.e("# Default", "is PROPERY_WRITE | PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE");
                        writableChar = mDefaultChar;
                    } else {
                        Log.e("# De ", "is not writable");
                        mDefaultChar = null;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (isWritableCharacteristic(chr)) {
                    Log.e("# user ", "GattCharacteristic is PROPERY_WRITE | PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE");
                    writableChar = chr;
                } else {
                    Log.e("# user ", "GattCharacteristic is not writable");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            writableChar.setValue(data);
            writableChar.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(writableChar);
            mDefaultChar = writableChar;
            return true;
        }

        public void setWritableCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic chr) {
            mDefaultChar = chr;
        }

        public ArrayList<BluetoothGattService> getServices() {
            return mGattServices;
        }

        public ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> getCharacteristics() {
            return mGattCharacteristics;
        }

        public ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> getWritableCharacteristics() {
            return mWritableCharacteristics;
        }


        /*****************************************************
         *  Handler, Listener, Timer, Sub classes
         ******************************************************/

        // Various callback methods defined by the BLE API.
        private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    mState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                    Log.e(TAG, "# Connected to GATT server.");

                    gatt.discoverServices();

                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    mState = STATE_IDLE;
                    Log.e(TAG, "# Disconnected from GATT server.");
                    mBluetoothGatt = null;
                    mGattServices.clear();
                    mDefaultService = null;
                    mGattCharacteristics.clear();
                    mWritableCharacteristics.clear();
                    mDefaultChar = null;
                    mDefaultDevice = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            // New services discovered
            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "# New GATT service discovered.");
                    checkGattServices(gatt.getServices());
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "# onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
                }
            }

            @Override
            // Result of a characteristic read operation
            public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    // We've received data from remote
                    Log.e(TAG, "# Read characteristic11111: " + String.format("%02X",characteristic.getValue()));

                /*
                 * onCharacteristicChanged callback receives same message
                 *
                final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
                if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                    //for(byte byteChar : data)
                    //  stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                    stringBuilder.append(data);
                    Log.e(TAG, stringBuilder.toString());

                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, new String(data)).sendToTarget();
                }

                if(mDefaultChar == null && isWritableCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                    mDefaultChar = characteristic;
                }
                */
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                // We've received data from remote
                byte[] newValue = characteristic.getValue();
                Log.e(TAG, "# onCharacteristicChanged: " + String.format("%02X",newValue));

                final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
                if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                    //for(byte byteChar : data)
                    //  stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                    stringBuilder.append(data);
                    Log.e(TAG, stringBuilder.toString());
                }

                if (mDefaultChar == null && isWritableCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                    mDefaultChar = characteristic;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

3 things:

- First make sure you have permissions. Requires `Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH permission.`
- Make sure your service/characteristic is correct.
- Override `onDescriptorWrite` and check what you have done with `writeDescriptor` from there. If there is a problem, the `onDescriptorWrite` will tell you.

Google docs about BLE are not that good. Therefore, [this](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/) amazing article will help you solve any issue with BLE.